# How to build static library for iOS on linux

Tags: c++, ios, linux

I have c++ static library written on linux. 
Is it possible to build this library for iOS?

I have installed g++-arm-linux-gnueabi, but when i try to do this:

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-g++-4.7 main.cpp -o mn -march=armv7
```

output is:

```
target CPU does not support ARM mode
```

Thanks and sorry for my english

Comment: You should compile your C++ library and all its dependencies for ARM with your cross-compiler; so you need some iOS system libraries...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

0: If you don't have source code, then it's impossible. Else read below:

1: Create a new `C/C++ library` in XCode(Below `OS X->Framework & Library`).

2: Put **ALL** your header files into a dictionary(It's not a must but it will help a lot to organize your project later, and also your header import path).

3: Import your source code into library project.

4: Drag library project dictionary into project window you want to import. Remember **ONLY** keep header files outside library project, remove anything else to prevent some unexpected issue caused by XCode when compiling. It's hard to explain with words, just let me show you a screenshot:

[image: keep header files outside library project]

5: Set dependencies & header search path, then you are good to go.

Sounds quite easy, right? Don't be fooled.

You will meet many detailed problems such as XCode can't find your header paths, link error(symbol not found), compiler error or using wrong C++ standards, CPU architecture..... etc.

But these can be solved, just give it a try, and it's worth trying :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no supported way to build iOS applications or libraries on any platform other than Mac OS X.

Take the source code to the library to a Mac, import it into an Xcode project, and try there.